# ECTO -- Ordering by count on many-to-many relationships

Tags: elixir, ecto

Preface:

I've been building a simple stackoverflow clone in the past few months to teach myself elixir, ecto, and the phoenix framework. I haven't had this much fun building things in a while.

Question:

I am at the point where I trying to sort questions by the number of upvotes that it has received.

Here is my question schema:

```
schema "questions" do
    ... 
    belongs_to :user, User

    has_many :answers, Answer
    has_many :upvotes, QuestionUpvote

    many_to_many :upvoting_users, User, join_through: QuestionUpvote

    timestamps
end
```

Here is my upvote schema:

```
schema "question_upvotes" do
    belongs_to :question, Question
    belongs_to :user, User

    timestamps
end
```

After a few hours of googling and reading through various Ecto documents, here's the query that I came up with.

Specifically, I want to find all questions posted today, and sorted by the number of upvotes that it has received.

```
questions_sort_by_upvotes =
    from q in Question,
    left_join: up in assoc(q, :upvotes),
    where: q.inserted_at == ^ Timex.today
    order_by: [desc: count(up.id), desc: q.inserted_at],
    group_by: q.id,
    select: q,
    preload: [:answers, :upvotes, :user]

questions = Repo.all(questions_sort_by_upvotes)
```

Now, I have a few questions for the experts here:

1. From what I've seen, the query seems to work. However, can I improve the query in any other ways (e.g. make the query more succinct, improve the query to make it faster)?
2. I understand that I can also create indices to make the query
   faster. Can someone give me pointers or point me to the right
   direction to what indices I should create for this specific query?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: The query seems fine to me but I am not an expert in SQL. Regarding the indexes, you could add index for `question_id` column in `upvotes` table to speed the joining up.

Comment: @JustMichael ... thanks for the confirmation. Having a someone telling me my query looks ok is very comforting :)

Comment: One thing you might consider is using [Fragments](http://angelika.me/2016/09/10/how-to-order-by-the-result-of-select-count-in-ecto/).